# How to Send Pdf as MMS by Twilo Using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pdf, twilio, twilio-api

I have a Test Twilio Number which is capable to send SMS,MMS,Voice Call . I am Successful in sending SMS and Voice call .

I am facing a challenge to send PDF as MMS .. As per the [TwilioDocs Accepted-mime-types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/accepted-mime-types) PDF is a Supported Type.

While  am trying to Send by using the Syntax :-

```
var accountSid = '<accountSid >';   
var authToken = '<authToken>';       
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
         client.messages.create({
            to: "<validnum>",
            from: "<validFrom>",  
            body: "Test Message ",
            mediaUrl: "http://docdro.id/GAak2pV"
            mediaContentType:"pdf"
        }, function(err, message) {
            if(err){
                console.log('Error Alert For Message '+JSON.stringify(err));
            }else{
                console.log(message.sid);
            }
        });
```

With the Above Code i can able to send JPG/PNG but PDF is being Failed by an Error:-

```
(Error: 30008) Unknown error. None
```

I have no clue Totally !! Somebody help me with a Saving Suggestion 
Thanks,
Prasad.

Comment: There is more information about that error here https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005750588
Only gif, png and jpeg are fully supported. Is your mediaUrl correctly pointing to a PDF file with the correct content type headers as your example seems to be a webpage, not a PDF file. Maybe try https://www.docdroid.net/file/download/GAak2pV/fax-1.pdf

Comment: S3 amzon Hosted Url is going successfully as attachment but the drop box rpoper url is not being supported ...  https://www.dropbox.com/s/hby1u0sww4kg069/fax.pdf it is failing with same error

Comment: Again, this isn't linking directly to a PDF file but to a webpage where you can view/download the file (after signing in), so it isn't going to work.

Comment: I got it buddy that make sense ThumbsUp!! facepalm

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Andy is pointing out in the comments, the URL to DropBox that you are using is actually pointing towards an HTML page that contains your PDF. You need the direct link to the PDF file itself, Twilio does not do any work to discover the PDF file within pages.

If you can host the file on S3, or anywhere else publicly, yourself then you will have more luck with this.

Comment: Yes with s3 it is working fine !! I got what i missed