# How to Send a PDF as MMS by Twilo Using Java?

Tags: java, pdf, mms, twilio-api

I can send an MMS message with a graphic image (*.jpg) and view it on my Android phone. However, when I try PDF, the PDF file does not show up my phone. I sent to an iPhone, but the receiving SMS app said that it couldn't handle the incoming PDF.
I the NodeJS sample, there was a property: 'mediaContentType:"pdf"'. I didn't notice the same in Java.
[How to Send Pdf as MMS by Twilo Using Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640496/how-to-send-pdf-as-mms-by-twilo-using-nodejs)

```
  package twilio;
  import com.twilio.Twilio;
  import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
  import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
  import java.net.URI;
  import java.net.URISyntaxException;

  public class SendMsgMMS {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "<my Twilio SID>";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "<my Twilio Auth code>";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    String fromPhoneNumber = "+11231231234";
    String toPhoneNumber = "+15551231234";
    Message message = Message.creator(
              new PhoneNumber(toPhoneNumber),
              new PhoneNumber(fromPhoneNumber),
              "Sample PDF"
            )
              .setMediaUrl(new URI("http://tigerfarmpress.com/books/download/HyperCubes02vSa.pdf"))
              .create();
    System.out.print("+ from:" + message.getFrom());
    System.out.print(", to:" + toPhoneNumber);
    System.out.print(", " + message.getSid());
    System.out.print(", " + message.getBody());
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}